# Instagram automation with selenium (Python) - Follow and unfollow button

Tags: python, selenium, instagram

I am trying to implement a function which is able to click on the button "follow" when I do not follow the user yet, but that is also able to ignore this part of the code when the text of the button is "unfollow", that means I am already a follower of the user.

The code I used is the following:

```py
Follow_Button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Follow']")
Follow_Button.click()
```

How can i add an exception to specify to selenium that it should skip this line of code when the text is different from "Follow"?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
try:
    Follow_Button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Follow']")
    Follow_Button.click()
except:
    pass
```

Comment: Do not use execptions for expected conditions. This should be handled by an if statement.

Comment: Hi Mohen, I liked your proposed solution. This allowed me to easy track with a variable if the button has been clicked or not. Consider that this code was part of a loop for a list of scraped instragram users, hence the final version is:                                                               
    try:
    Follow_Button = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='Follow']")
    Follow_Button.click()
    Followed="1"
except:
     Followed="0"
pass

Answer (score 0):

If selenium doesn't find an element with that text it will raise `NoSuchElementException`. You can import this with

```py
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
```

Keep in mind that `find_element_by_xpath` and `find_elements_by_xpath` are different. The `elements` version will return an empty list instead of raising an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check the **text** of the element*(in this case the button)*, Apply an if condition to check if the text if "Follow". If yes, do click.

```
button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("class_name")

if button.text == "Follow":
   button.click()
```

For this I suggest finding the element not by the text, but by any other attribute, an ID, class or an xpath but not with text, as it doesn't always contain it.

Hope this is what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `suppress` from [`contextlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html) alongside the [`NoSuchElementException`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html) from `selenium.common.exceptions`:

```py
from contextlib import suppress
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

...

with suppress(NoSuchElementException):
     Follow_Button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[text()="Follow"]')
     Follow_Button.click()
```

That way your script will just ignore this block of code if the `NoSuchElementException` get caught.